# attaching multiple files in html form and send them in email as attachment but this should be optional

Tags: php

this site has helped me a lot in creating my form. I am totally new to php and have created my php file by searching so many sites and with lot of help from experts. Please somebody help me in this also. I want to allow user to attach multiple files and send them to me as attachment. I want to keep this as optional i.e. if the user wants he may not attach the files or if he wishes he can attach multiple files and submit. Please help me in this. I am using phpmailer. As I am totally new to php, please let me know the code by making changes in my php file. All the thanks in advance. Saxena. My php is as follows:

```
<?php
/**
* Simple example script using PHPMailer with exceptions enabled
* @package phpmailer
* @version $Id$
*/

require 'class.phpmailer.php';

try {
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); //New instance, with exceptions enabled

$to = "saxena@designmaniac.in";
$mail->AddAddress($to);
$mail->From = $_POST['email'];
$mail->FromName = $_POST['name_f'];
$mail->Subject = "Admission Form";

$body = "<table>
<tr>
<th colspan='2'>Admission Form</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Course :</td>
<td>".$_POST['course']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Payment Mode :</td>
<td>".$_POST['p_mode']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Payment options :</td>
<td>".$_POST['p_option']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>First Name :</td>
<td>".$_POST['name_f']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Middle Name : </td>
<td>".$_POST['name_m']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Last Name : </td>
<td>".$_POST['name_l']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>E-mail : </td>
<td>".$_POST['email']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Date of Birth : </td>
<td>".$_POST['date']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Gender : </td>
<td>".$_POST['gender']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Nationality : </td>
<td>".$_POST['nationality']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Address : </td>
<td>".$_POST['address_line1']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>City : </td>
<td>".$_POST['city']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Zip Code : </td>
<td>".$_POST['zip']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>State : </td>
<td>".$_POST['state']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Country : </td>
<td>".$_POST['country']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Mobile Number : </td>
<td>".$_POST['mobile_number']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Father/Mother First Name : </td>
<td>".$_POST['fname_f']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Father/Mother Middle Name : </td>
<td>".$_POST['fname_m']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Father/Mother Last Name : </td>
<td>".$_POST['fname_l']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Father/Mother Mobile No : </td>
<td>".$_POST['mobile_number1']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Qualification : </td>
<td>".$_POST['qualification']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>University : </td>
<td>".$_POST['university']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Year : </td>
<td>".$_POST['year']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Qualification : </td>
<td>".$_POST['qualification_2']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>University : </td>
<td>".$_POST['university_2']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Year : </td>
<td>".$_POST['year_2']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Qualification : </td>
<td>".$_POST['qualification_3']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>University : </td>
<td>".$_POST['university_3']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Year : </td>
<td>".$_POST['year_3']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Discipline Information (School) : </td>
<td>".$_POST['discipline']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Discipline Information (Violation) : </td>
<td>".$_POST['violation']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>12th Mark List : </td>
<td>".$_POST['attachment1']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>12th Passing Certificate : </td>
<td>".$_POST['attachment2']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>10th Mark List : </td>
<td>".$_POST['attachment3']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>10th Passing Certificate : </td>
<td>".$_POST['attachment4']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Address Proof : </td>
<td>".$_POST['attachment8']."</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:bold'>Photographs : </td>
<td>".$_POST['attachment9']."</td>
</tr>

<table>";
$body = preg_replace('/\\\\/','', $body); //Strip backslashes
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // tell the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port = 25; // set the SMTP server port
//$mail->Host = "saxena@designmaniac.in"; // SMTP server
//$mail->Username = "name@domain.com"; // SMTP server username
//$mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP server password

$mail->IsSendmail(); // tell the class to use Sendmail
$mail->AddReplyTo("saxena@designmaniac.in");
$mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
$mail->WordWrap = 80; // set word wrap

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "pdf" && $imageFileType != "docx"
&& $imageFileType != "doc" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, pdf & Word files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if(!empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']) && !empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'])) {
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'],
$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
}
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
$mail->Send();
echo 'Thank You. Your form has been submitted';
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
echo $e->errorMessage();
}

?>
```